# Jupyter book build error: No template sub-directory with name 'script' found in the following paths

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, jupyter, jupyterbook

I have seen the similar questions but they aren't answering the issue I'm having. Whenever I try to build my jupyter-book it returns this error:

```
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'script' found in the following paths:
    /Users/san/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/san/Library/Python/3.8/share/jupyter
    /Users/san/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
```

I am not getting what is causing this error.